# Lucene - open a closed IndexWriter

Tags: java, lucene

Heres my issue, I perform add() to add documents to my index and then I close() it. That works great!

Now I have a new requirement and every time I save something in my DB I need to update my Index. I can't create again the indexWriter because it takes more than 4 minutes so I just need to update() or add() a document to the index.

To accomplish it, I'm not doing index.close(), I'm doing index.commit() after I populate my index... but i think it should be close and then open to update().

Any suggestion? THANKS!

Answer (score 11):

[`close`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#close%28%29) is a costly operation and the javadocs recommended that [`commit`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#commit%28%29) be used if you are updating frequently. The javadocs state that `close`:

> Commits all changes to an index and
>   closes all associated files. Note that
>   this may be a costly operation, so,
>   try to re-use a single writer instead
>   of closing and opening a new one.

I believe that the difference between `close` and `commit` is that `commit` only flushes the data to make it visible to readers whereas `close` optimises the index too. This makes `commit` about [5 times faster](http://rash0208.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/lucene-prefer-indexwriter-commit-over-indexwriter-close/) than `close`.

If you are adding data continuously, it is better to `commit` and then finally `close` when you are all done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking the same but I was open for second opinions!

Comment: wouldn't your index be locked if you just perform `commit()` and not `close()`, which prevents for sub-sequent writes to index?