# How to handle multiple IndexWriter and multiple cross-process IndexWriter

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am googling for two days... I really need help.

I have an application with multiple threads trying to update a lucene index using Open/Close of `IndexWriter` for each update. Threads can start at any time.

Yeah, the problem with `write.lock`! So there are may be two or more solutions:

1) check `IndexWriter.IsLocked(index)` and if it is locked to sleep the thread.
2) Open an `IndexWriter` and never close it. The problem is that I have another application using the same index. Also when should I close the index and finalize the whole process?

here are interesting postings
[Lucene IndexWriter thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899777/lucene-indexwriter-thread-safety)
[Lucene - open a closed IndexWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865183/lucene-open-a-closed-indexwriter?rq=1)

**Update:**
Exactly 2 years later I did a rest API which wraps [this](https://github.com/NielsKuhnel/NrtManager) and all writes and reads were routed to the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple threads, same process:

Keep your `IndexWriter` opened, and share it across multiple thread. The `IndexWriter` is threadsafe.

For multiple processes, your solution #1 is prone to issues with race conditions. You would need to use named `Mutex` to implement it safely:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k.aspx

That being said, I'd personally opt for a process dedicated to writing to the index, and communicate with it using something like WCF.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about something like external process handling the index updates. What are the consequences of not closing the index writer but doing only commit? Is there something I should consider to do manually regarding IndexReader and index fragment merge?

Comment: It all depends on the volume of new documents and the MergePolicy you use. Usually you'll want to Optimize (IndexWriter.Optimize()) on low traffic hours. Keeping the IndexWriter opened is usually better if your Searchers are created in the same process, because you can use near real time search: http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch

Comment: What about the searchers in different process?

Comment: You will need to detect changes to the index and re-open them, or periodically re-open them to see changes.

Comment: Exactly 2 years later I did a rest API which wraps this: https://github.com/NielsKuhnel/NrtManager and all writes and reads were routed to the API.